# multiple filters in google openrefine

Tags: openrefine

I have a following table in googlerefine,

```
Host    Plugin Output 3
1   -
1   KB2932677
1   (MS14-014)
1   (2
1   vulnerabilities)
-
1   KB2837617
1   (MS14-001)
1   (3
1   vulnerabilities)
-
1   KB2760415
1   (MS13-091)
```

I want output as all entereies with following criteria.

```
starting with KB
contains MS
```

the output will look like

```
1 KB2932677
1 MS14-014
1 KB2837617
1 MS14-001
```

I used filter value.startsWith("KB") or value.contains("MS")

but it just picks KB ones. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple facet together in OpenRefine for the same column.
In your case invoke two `Custom text facet` for your `Plugin Output 3`.

1. In the first one use the following expression: `value.startsWith('KB')`.
2. In the second one, use `value.contains('MS')`

Each facet will return a true / false filter. You can now select `true` on both of them to display your record.